# In Angular 2, how do I submit an input type="text" value upon pressing enter?

Tags: angular

I'm building a search box in my Angular 2 app, trying to submit the value upon hitting 'Enter' (the form does not include a button).

**Template**

```
<input type="text" id="search" class="form-control search-input" name="search" placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]="query" (ngSubmit)="this.onSubmit(query)">
```

With a simple onSubmit function for testing purposes...

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  onSubmit(value: string): void {
    alert('Submitted value: ' + value);
  }
}
```

ngSubmit doesn't seem to work in this case. So what is the 'Angular 2 way' to solve this? (Preferably without hacks like hidden buttons)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`(keyup.enter)="methodInsideYourComponent()"` add this inside your input tag

Comment: Nice! I was getting it to work by wrapping it with `<form (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)"><input type="text" /></form>`, but your way is much cleaner and concise!

Comment: This is also mentioned in [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html#!#key-event-filtering-with-key-enter-) .

Comment: also, you can send info of the input via `methodInsideYourComponent($event)` and access it on the method `evt.target.value`

Answer (score 3):

You can put this text box inside a form tag and set ngSubmit event on form i.e.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="YouMethod()">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In normal HTML you need a `<button type="submit" ></button>` or `<input type="submit" />` to submit the form when pressing enter. These elements can be hidden by css but must be present inside the form. `ng-submit` should be bound to the normal `onsubmit` event and it has the same conditions to be triggered.

Also from the code you have posted, you have no form element but only the input field, and the `ng-submit` directive only works with forms because input elements have no `onsubmit` JS event.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this solution worked for me as well:

```
<form (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)"><input type="text" /></form>
```